# How to pass new params to previous screen in react native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I have a flatlist of movies when a user clicks on it, it passes param to movie details screen and movie detail is shown then that screen has flatlist of similar movies when user selects any of it, basically new params should be passed to movie details screen but no, it is just working as if i am tapping on back button....

```
onPress={() =>
              this.props.navigation.navigate('MovieDetails', {
                selectedItem: item,
              })
            }   // Passing params to movie details screen


console.log(this.props.navigation.getParam('selectedItem')) //receiving params in movie details screen
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this below example. Hope this will help you.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, marginBottom: 10 }}>Home Screen</Text>
        <Button
          title="Go to Details"
          onPress={() =>
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Details', {
              name: 'this params from homescreen',
            })
          }
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class DetailsScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log('screen', this.props.navigation.state);

    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, marginBottom: 10 }}>
          {this.props.navigation.state.params.name}
        </Text>
        <Button
          title="Go back"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const RootStack = createStackNavigator({
  Home: HomeScreen,
  Details: DetailsScreen,
});

export default createAppContainer(RootStack);
```

Feel free for doubts.

Comment: I have noticed that when i explicitly refresh the code then new params are shown, i don't know why..

Comment: if possible could you share your  detail screen source code

Comment: `constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        tmdbmovieinfo: [],
         isLoading: false,
    }
} 
    componentDidMount(){
    this.moviefetch(this.props.navigation.getParam('selectedItem').id)
}

moviefetch = (id) => {
    fetch('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/'+id+'?api_key=xxx&language=en-US')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
        this.setState({
            tmdbmovieinfo: responseJson,
            isLoading: false
        })
})}`

Comment: if you are going to fetch data again in the detail screen for similar movies.  you have to use **componentDidUpdate()**, **componentDidMount** will execute only once, when React component mounted and it doesn't execut when state or props changed

Comment: Or you can fetch data aging in detail sceen by using onPress

Comment: Yes!! componentDidUpdate() did the desired job :)